# How can I add an object inside another object (NodeJS, Axion, Cheerio, jQuery, JSON)

Tags: jquery, arrays, node.js, json, object

I'm trying to learn Axion & Cheerio using NodeJS for Web Scraping...
I was doing fine, until i stumbled on an issue while trying to nicely save the gotten data into a JSON file.
I've always struggled with arrays, objects & formatting JSON files... I would truly appreciate if someone could help me out a bit & maybe link some useful sources for that matter.

Here is the code that I'm using right now:

```js
    if (response.status === 200) {
            const html = response.data;
            let $ = cheerio.load(html);
            const data = {
                animes: {
                    details: [],
                    episodes: []
                }
            };
            $('.item').each(function (i) {
                data.animes.details.push({
                    id: i - 3,
                    title: $(this).children('.inner').children('.name').text().trim(),
                    url: $(this).children('.inner').children('.name').prop('href'),
                    poster: $(this).children('.inner').children('.poster').children('img').prop('src')
                });

                data.animes.episodes.push({
                    episode: $(this).children('.inner').children('a').children('.status').children('.ep').text().trim()
                });
            });

            data.animes.details = data.animes.details.slice(4, -21);

            fs.writeFile('data/animes.json',
                JSON.stringify(data, null, 4), (err) => {
                    console.log('File successfully written!');
                });
        }
```

Currently my JSON file looks something like this:

```
{
    "weeb": {
        "details": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Some title 1",
                "url": "https://placeholder.com",
                "poster": "https://lets-imagine-a-picture.com/picture01.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Some title 2",
                "url": "https://placeholder.com",
                "poster": "https://lets-imagine-a-picture.com/picture01.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "episodes": [
            {
                "episode": "3/12"
            },
            {
                "episode": "13/32"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want my JSON file to look like this:

```
{
    "weeb": {
        "details": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Some title 1",
                "url": "https://placeholder.com",
                "poster": "https://lets-imagine-a-picture.com/picture01.jpg",
                "episodes": [
                    {
                        "episode-01": "https://some-nifty-link.com/episode01",
                        "episode-02": "https://some-nifty-link.com/episode02",
                        ...
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Some title 2",
                "url": "https://placeholder.com",
                "poster": "https://lets-imagine-a-picture.com/picture01.jpg",
                "episodes": [
                    {
                        "episode-01": "https://some-nifty-link.com/episode01",
                        "episode-02": "https://some-nifty-link.com/episode02",
                        ...
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to recommend a better structure for doing this, If i'm truly trying to do this wrong :'D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example below. Loop through the inner children, and push the found object episodes into to the array index of `data.animes.details[i]` in the object `episodes`. I don't think it is the most neat solution. But if the key of the children is correct it should work.

```js
    if (response.status === 200) {
            const html = response.data;
            let $ = cheerio.load(html);
            const data = {
                animes: {
                    details: [],
                }
            };
            $('.item').each(function (i) {
                data.animes.details.push({
                    id: i - 3,
                    title: $(this).children('.inner').children('.name').text().trim(),
                    url: $(this).children('.inner').children('.name').prop('href'),
                    poster: $(this).children('.inner').children('.poster').children('img').prop('src')
                });

                $(this).children('.inner').each(function (j) {
                  data.animes.details[i].episodes.push({
                    episode: $(this).children('.inner').children('a').children('.status').children('.ep').text().trim()
                  });
                });
            });
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked & this was what i was looking for :)
Now that I look at it, it makes a lot of sense & I feel dumb :D